# Insert given string value in mysql database as datetime with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to insert in mysql database a string value as a datetime. I'm using myqli in php.

```
<?php
class DBConnection {
    private $conn;
    function __construct() {
    }
    function connect() {
        include_once dirname(__FILE__).'/ConstEmployee.php';
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to database".mysqli_connect_err();
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

Here is my function for inserting the value:

```
public function createCustomerOrder($id, $pickup_address, $delivery_address, $weight, $volume, $order_date) {
        $op = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (ID_customer, pickup_address, delivery_address, weight, volume, order_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, STR_TO_DATE(?,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'))");
        
        $op->bind_param("issdds", $id, $pickup_address, $delivery_address, $weight, $volume, $order_date);
        
        if($op->execute()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

My function returns 1 and the row is inserted in database but order_date column is null.

Exemple of given date value: 22-08-2020 10:10:10

Comment: If i insert 2020-08-22 10:10:10 the column is still null

Comment: I created it in phpmyadmin. If i  enter in cosole the following query it works fine. INSERT INTO orders (ID_customer, pickup_address, delivery_address,
            weight, volume, order_date) 
            VALUES (1, 'A', 'B', 40.02, 50.5, STR_TO_DATE('22-08-2020 10:10:10','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'))

Comment: What is your table schema for `order_date`?

Comment: In orders table i have a datetime type column order_date.

Comment: Why not fix the date first !?!?!

Comment: I've tried this: $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $_POST['order_date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  and changed mysql : "INSERT INTO orders (ID_customer, pickup_address, delivery_address, weight, volume, order_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" but still doesn't work